# Anyway for Iphone can be tricked to receive non-Supported Bluetooth profiles?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

Is there any way to trick the iphone into communicating / connecting to a non-bluetooth 2.4  ghz device?

Any way to further trick the iphone into believing that device was bluetooth?

I want to control an RC toy with my iphone without using a bluetooth receiver in the toy. Looking for the cheapest way to control a $10 toy with iphone really.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible: Bluetooth and radio-control protocol(s) are very distinct, and share almost nothing. I use plural for radio-control protocols because there are many ones...

The only thing they share is base frequency, but WiFi, microwave ovens, baby monitoring video cameras share it also.

If you want some more details on how various RC protocols handle interference (the reason why it's almost impossible to control a toy by interfering via Bluetooth), have a look there: http://www.rcmodelreviews.com/spreadspectrum03.shtml

To control your toy (something I'm attempting right now!), I think the way is the following:

- Have an Arduino (or other micro controller, but Arduino is really easy I think) plugged to your RC car controllers (use PWM outputs to connect servo motors, and if you're lucky enough, the motor driver will react the same way...) Cheapest Arduino can be in the 5$ range (Arduino Pro Mini copy from some Hong-Kong company)
- Have a Bluetooth Low Energy (a.k.a BTLE, Bluetooth 4, Bluetooth Smart) receiver plugged on RX/TX pins on the Arduino. Nordic Semi has some for around 20$ sold by Adafruit Technology, but you may find lower prices (I did not... currently!)
- Design and implement a custom BTLE protocol in your iPhone app AND in your Arduino so the app can send commands to the Arduino, which could answer with data/status (think battery monitor...)

Good luck, and have fun!

Comment: Afterthough: BEWARE, it will only work with BTLE enabled iOS devices (iPhone 5 and over, iPad 3 and over, iPod touch 5g and over) Previous models only support 2.1 bluetooth "classical", which requires MFI (Made For iPod) program and specific encryption hardware from Apple...